# Error reproducing Auth0 instructions on “Ruby On Rails API: Authentication”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt, auth0, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I used the quick start [“Ruby On Rails API: Authentication”](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/rails/01-authorization) successfully. Created an API and everything works just fine. Then I tried to recreate the code but including all this on an existing Rails app and got an error.

The demo (working for me before) include this call to the JWT gem:

```rb
JWT.decode(token, nil, # <----
    true, # Verify the signature of this token
    algorithm: "RS256",
    iss: "https://" + ENV["AUTH0_DOMAIN"],
    verify_iss: true,
    aud: ENV["AUTH0_AUDIENCE"],
    verify_aud: true)
```

<s>The second parameter with nil assigned, in the demo works, but in my project leads me to a JWT Error, understanding that the parameter used for public_key shouldn’t be null. But it’s null in the demo and works</s>(UPDATE: The nil message seems to come from another object reference). I’m kind of a newbie with JWT matters.

Error message:

```
undefined method `verify' for nil:NilClass
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/security_utils.rb:20:in `verify_rsa'

-------------------------------
Backtrace:
-------------------------------

  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/security_utils.rb:20:in `verify_rsa'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/algos/rsa.rb:15:in `verify'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/signature.rb:44:in `verify'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/decode.rb:42:in `verify_signature'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/decode.rb:26:in `decode_segments'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt.rb:28:in `decode'
  /api/lib/json_web_token.rb:10:in `verify'
  /api/app/controllers/concerns/secured.rb:71:in `auth_token'
  /api/app/controllers/concerns/secured.rb:50:in `authenticate_request!'
```

`json_web_token.rb` and `secured.rb` are identical to the sample. `jwt-2.2.1` it's the same gem version used in both environments.

The only difference I found between the environments of the demo and my legacy project was the Rails version, 5 in the demo, and 4.x on mine. I can’t upgrade right now, so if you think in another thing I can be doing wrong it would be helpful.

*Update 2: Including sample code*

I'm including here the code for the jwks_hash method, it's the same in both environments. I just added logger lines to the original. You can see the differences in the output for both environments below.

```rb
def self.jwks_hash
    Rails.logger.warn '---> hashing'
    Rails.logger.warn "https://#{Rails.application.secrets.auth0_domain}/.well-known/jwks.json"
    jwks_raw = Net::HTTP.get URI("https://#{Rails.application.secrets.auth0_domain}/.well-known/jwks.json")
    Rails.logger.warn jwks_raw
    jwks_keys = Array(JSON.parse(jwks_raw)['keys'])
    Rails.logger.warn '---> jwks_keys'
    Rails.logger.warn jwks_keys  # Check output of this below 
    Hash[
      jwks_keys
      .map do |k|
        [
          k['kid'],
          OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
            Base64.decode64(k['x5c'].first)
          ).public_key
        ]
      end
    ]
  end
```

**Output in working demo:**

```
W, [...]  WARN -- : [{"alg"=>"RS256", "kty"=>"RSA", "use"=>"sig", "n"=>"yDsoJbr45jlrCDQSu8X6ZAko......"]}]

W, [...]  WARN -- : {"alg"=>"RS256", "typ"=>"JWT", "kid"=>"YHEH94lH9itYZUhLx3hee"}
```

**Output in my project:**

```
W, [...]  WARN -- : [{"alg"=>"RS256", "kty"=>"RSA", "use"=>"sig", "n"=>"yDsoJbr45jlrCDQSu8X6ZAko......"]}]

W, [...]  WARN -- : [{"alg"=>"RS256", "kty"=>"RSA", "use"=>"sig", "n"=>"yDsoJbr45jlrCDQSu8X6ZAko......"]}]
```

The second element it's the only point of difference between the runs I could found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the situation with a workaround. I used the gem `json-jwt` instead of `jwt` and modify my code ends like this:

```rb
expected_iss = 'https://'+ENV['AUTH0_DOMAIN']+'/'
expected_aud = ENV['AUTH0_AUDIENCE']

begin
    jwk_set = JSON::JWK::Set.new(
        JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get URI(ENV['AUTH0_RSA_DOMAIN']))
        )
    id_token = JSON::JWT.decode token, jwk_set
    unless (id_token[:iss] == expected_iss) # && id_token[:aud] == expected_aud)
    #raise 'ID Token Verification Failed!'
    false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The demo fetches a public key in the function `self.jwks_hash` and the public key seems to be `nil` looking at the file throwing the error [security_util.rb](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt/blob/f60d78a2377b754bfb91f48b0c04b660324d805b/lib/jwt/security_utils.rb#L20). So it appears you are missing a step for fetching the public key.

When you encode with RS256, or another algorithm for that matter, you need to decode with a key. Only when you use `'none'` you don't need a key to decode. See more on [the docs](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt).

Comment: Thanks. Look, I download the sample and works with the steps in there. I reproduce the very same steps to my env and didn't work, I got that `nil` error. However, I try to pass a public key object as the second parameter and the same error remains. Anyway, the second attribute is `nil` on the demo steps. I think I'm missing some env stuff. I'm not sure which data can I add updating the question to clarify the situation, at this moment I only post about the difference in Rails versions.

Comment: @nilsandrey do you want to update with your full code? the sample has the static method jwks_hash can you add the rest? Also did you generate the jwt with the private key that matches that public key?

Comment: I'll update some code on monday from my project. The demo code it's complete on the published link. About the key match yes I did. The error received remains about a nil object, not a mitshmach.

Comment: I updated the question now to include `jwks_hash` code, like the sample but just point out the output source for the difference in logs output.

Comment: I'm near to find the problem and will post here later. I'm not marking the answer as the solution because it's not related to creating the key but by using bad parameters. However, because of the time window and you are the only one paying some attention I'll grant you the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: @nilsandrey sorry my answer didn't help, there was no need to give me the bounty but thanks :D It looks like what you are getting back from your domain is different between these two environments, is it the same domain? please post your solution when you find it - I'm curious to see what was the problem

Comment: I think maybe I didn't understand the whole scenario. The error is gone when: 
- Switched from gem `jwt` to `json-jwt` for token decoding and
validation.
- Fix a dummy typo on the audience or auth0_domain field, a simple '/' at the end that shouldn't be there. 
I should write more when the project finishes.